# Error when providing HTML5 audio with a base64 encoded Data URI as source

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, audio, html5-audio

Firefox supports playing ogg files using HTML5 audio. So, I am trying to load HTML5 audio with a base64 encoded Data URI as the source. Consider the example given on website https://iandevlin.com/html5/data-uri/audio.php and check the audio metadata information on Firefox browser.

Note, intermittently the metadata loaded by audio tag is wrong. Current time is not displayed in the audio control view. Also, the audio duration is displayed as 00:00 but while checking using JavaScript code it is infinity. When I click on play button the audio is directly seeking to end. In short, audio plays but all the other metadata is wrong.

My expectation is audio base64 encoded Data URI should have loaded correctly. Audio metadata should display information correctly. Also, audio should play fine.

[image: Audio Duration is infinity]

[image: Play is not working correctly]

Comment: well first of all please set '<meta charset="UTF-8" />' under the '<head>' tag so the big red error is gone. For the problem you are asking about have you tried going to the network tab, reload the page and see if there are 404 responses?

Comment: I also had this problem in Firefox when displaying <audio/> for base64 encoded data. Its total length of audio is 36:16:58 (36 hours). This is not a reasonable number.